# Catch word occurring multiple times within quotes

Tags: php, regex

I need to catch all instances and variants of a class name using regex, but i can't figure out the correct pattern, currently it match the whole text inside quotes

I intend to use the pattern with php preg_replace_callback()

```
['"].*([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*elementor[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*).*['"]
```

The text i test is

```
$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass('elementor-edit new-elementor-invisible class-new');
$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass('elementor-loading elementor-invisible');
$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass('media noelementor');
```

Demo can be found at https://regex101.com/r/ykVhYy/3

With above pattern it catch the following:

Match 1: **elementor-invisible**

Match 2: **elementor-invisible**

Match 3: **elementor**

***The expected results*** should be the following:

Text line 1: **elementor-edit, new-elementor-invisible**

Text Line 2: **elementor-loading, elementor-invisible**

Text Line 3: no match

Comment: Will the [hasClass()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_hasclass.asp) function work here?

Comment: No sorry, i'am just parsing the JavaScript code (my text example) using regex, not actual run of the JS code.

Comment: Can you add the callback that you are trying and an example or two of matches (using actual input, quotes, special-characters, etc)?

Comment: I could use ['"](.*?)['"]  to catch all text inside the the  quotes, but i need a way to narrow down and see for exact match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in PHP using `\G` directive:

```
(?:'|(?!^)\G)\h*(?:([\w-]*\belementor\b[\w-]*)|[\w-]+)\b(?=[\w\h-]*')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ykVhYy/10)

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `(?=[\w\h-]*')` is a positive lookahead to assert that we have a closing single quote ahead after 0 or more word or space or hyphen characters.

Note that, your matches are available in captured group #1.

**PHP Code:**

```
$re = '/(?:'|(?!^)\G)\h*(?:([\w-]*\belementor\b[\w-]*)|[\w-]+)\b(?=[\w\h-]*')/m';
$str = '$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass(\'elementor-edit new-elementor-invisible class-new\');
$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass(\'elementor-loading elementor-invisible\');
$backgroundVideoContainer.addClass(\'media noelementor\');';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the match result from group #1
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192129/discussion-on-answer-by-anubhava-catch-word-occurring-multiple-times-within-quot).